# What are L, S, and F phonemes?

Tags: untagged

On the Procgenesis language generator, you find these five Phoneme types: C,V,L,S,& F. I believe that C and V are Consonants and Vowels respectively, but nothing I look at can explain the rest. The link is here: http://procgenesis.com/LanguageGen/langgen.html

Comment: Note that you should not assume that abstract symbols L, S, F in other sources (books etc.) have the same meaning as on that page. E.g. L could mean any [Lateral consonant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lateral_consonant) and S could mean any [Sibilant consonant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sibilant).

Comment: I meant like looking up lists of phoneme types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a bit of experimentation, it seems:

L is liquids: consonants that can appear after a C in an onset.

S is starts: consonants that can appear before a C in an onset.

F is finals: consonants that can appear in a syllable coda.

Comment: Also at the bottom of that page, there is text "Based on Martin O' Leary's naming-language code found [here](https://github.com/mewo2/naming-language)". Then you can read source code at https://github.com/mewo2/naming-language/blob/master/language.js

Comment: @Arfrever That would make a good answer of its own!

Comment: That github page has reference to http://mewo2.com/notes/naming-language/ which currently does not exist, but older version found through archive.org (e.g. https://web.archive.org/web/20230624155015/http://mewo2.com/notes/naming-language/) apparently uses S to mean Sibilants, and includes that /f/ amongst sibilants...